# Using additional OAuthSignatureMethods with RestSharp?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I've used RestSharp in the past for communicating with RESTful APIs, so it was my go-to solution for a recent project I'm working on.

However, for this particular API, they specify using HMAC‐SHA256 as the OAUTH signature method. This isn't one of the OAuthSignatureMethods available with RestSharp. Is there a way to add this, or to otherwise use HMAC-SHA256 with RestSharp? Or do I need to go back and do it manually?